# Geoserver renders reprojected raster only as transparent images

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, coordinate-system

Trying to reproject WMS layers in geoserver from the default of EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3574

Using the default projection works fine.
  url = `/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ENSEMBLE:global_360x181.air_temp.ht_sfc,base_layers:coastlines&styles=,line&bbox=-180.5,-90.5,180.5,90.5&width=658&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers`
results in:
[image: surface air tempurature grid in EPSG:4326]

Changing only the SRS and BBOX only renders the vector data, not the raster data:
  url = /geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=base_layers:coastlines,ENSEMBLE:global_360x181.air_temp.ht_sfc&styles=line,&bbox=-1054375,-105875,2584375,2596875&width=658&height=330&srs=EPSG:3574&format=application/openlayers

results in:
[image]

The raster layer is there - I can make a getFeatureInfo request, but geoserver styles it as completely transparent.  There is absolutely nothing in the geoserver log.  I have logging turned on at the 'INFO' level.

I tried editing the WCS Settings on the publishing tab for this layer and explicitly added EPSG:3574 to the Current Request and Response SRS List.  No effect. I also verified that in the WMS Settings Limited SRS List, EPSG:3574 is listed.

The GeoWebCache is disabled for this layer.

I am completely stumped.
Half-baked ideas welcome.

**Update**

I just recreated this behavior in both Geoserver 2.7.1 and 2.2.4, so either I am doing something completely wrong, or this behavior has been in geoserver for a long time, which seems remarkable.

**Update #2**

In an attempt to eliminate any configuration issues in my geoserver:

1. Downlaoded the latest stable geoserver.war, 2.7.1.1 and installed in Tomcat.
2. Request the nurc:Img_Sample in EPSG:4326, OK
3. Request the topp:states in EPSG:4326, OK
4. Request the nurc:Img_Sample in EPSG:32615, not OK
5. Request the topp:states in EPSG:32615. works fine.

I get the exact same results as originally described. Transparent image, responds to get feature info requests.

Img_Sample URL in UTM 15N projection:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nurc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nurc:Img_Sample&styles=&bbox=166021.44,0.00,534994.66,9329005.18&width=768&height=372&srs=EPSG:32615&format=image/png

**Update #3**

There is one raster in the default data set in a non-EPSG:4326 projection.  The native projection for sfdem is EPSG:26713.  This layer renders in both EPSG:26713 and EPSG:4326.  Is it possible that geoserver will only reproject when the native SRS is a 'PROJCS'?  EPSG:4326 is a 'GEOGCS' - might this make a difference?

Comment: This might be an Openlayers issue as I can't reproduce it using QGis to make a similar request to my local GeoServer.

Comment: @iant does this happen in the layer previewer of your local geoserver?  This is the open layers instance I made the screen shots from.

Comment: that's an old and cut down version of OpenLayers - I wouldn't use it for anything. In my version it has been updated to OL3 so isn't comparable

Comment: I'm using the layer preview as a simple way to take any of my software out of the equation.  If I curl a geoserver request & set the format=image/png, I get the same results.

Comment: ```url = /geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=base_layers:coastlines,ENSEMBLE:global_360x181.air_temp.ht_sfc&styles=line,&bbox=-1054375,-105875,2584375,2596875&width=658&height=330&srs=EPSG:3574&format=application/openlayers``` There is an error in this request, for a  WMS 1.3.0 request the you need to use ```CRS=EPSG:3574``` not ```srs=EPSG:3574``` this will also affect the order of the coordinates in the bounding box.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but I assume, its about the distortion inherent to your Projection EPSG:3574 which is extremal because displaying the pole(s). I guess there's only data in your raster layer until around 85°N or something, and you are trying to display data further north.

You could try a projection that is "closer" to EPSG:4326 and then also first query the same BBOX

```
bbox=-180,-90,180,90
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem.  Image #1 shows the data is available globally.  Image #2 shows I can click on the image & get feature data back, so something should be rendered there.  Also, Image #2 shows data as far south as the Black Sea & Caspian sea, which should be more than far enough south, if the problem has something to do with clipping regions north of 85°N.  For the record, gdalinfo indicates the corner coordinates for the raster layer extend from -180 to +180, -90 to +90

Comment: One could argue I am trying to eliminate distortion by using the equal area projection and that it is the distortion inherent in EPSG:4326 that I am trying to remove, but distortion is not what my question is about at all actually.

Comment: ok, you're right about the distortion, it's in the EPSG:4326 actually. Still, did you try another projection, if it works?

Comment: I have tried several.  PDC Mercator (EPSG:3832) and several UTM projections (EPSG:32638, etc.).

Comment: Does the GetFeatureInfo from your raster layer yield the same value for a unique position in both cases?

Comment: I have not verified the exact pixel registration, but it's close.